# Output Go time in RFC3339 like MySQL format

Tags: go, rfc3339

In Holland we mostly use YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS. How can I format that in Go? Everything I insert (even according the standard) gives weird numbers.

This is my code (`p.Created` is a `NanoSeconds int64` object):

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "log"
    "time"
)

const createdFormat = "2010-01-01 20:01:00" //"Jan 2, 2006 at 3:04pm (MST)"

type Post struct {
    Id      int64
    Created int64
    Title   string
    Body    string
}

func main() {
    // Establish database connection
    dsn := "root@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/testdb"
    con, err := sql.Open("mysql", dsn)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Couldn't connect to databse:", err)
    } else {
        log.Println("DB Connection established")
    }
    defer con.Close()

    // Try to get something
    row := con.QueryRow("SELECT * FROM posts LIMIT 1")
    p := new(Post)
    err = row.Scan(&p.Id, &p.Created, &p.Title, &p.Body)

    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Failed to fetch Post")
    }
    fmt.Println(p)
    fmt.Println(time.Unix(0, p.Created).Format(createdFormat))
}
```

I could just concat `time.Unix(0, p.Created).Year()` etc., but that's not very clean and is an annoyance for consistency.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There were two mistakes in the above. For the format you need to make the output of that special date/time, and the parameters to `time.Unix` are the other way round ([playground](http://play.golang.org/p/HGpwAg_7SJ))

```
const createdFormat = "2006-01-02 15:04:05" //"Jan 2, 2006 at 3:04pm (MST)"

fmt.Println(time.Unix(1391878657, 0).Format(createdFormat))
```

Comment: That worked, thanks. Weird that the docs state `func Unix(sec int64, nsec int64) Time` tho. Probably understand it wrong

Comment: `sec` is the number of seconds since the epoch; `nsec` is the number of nano-seconds after `sec`.

Comment: re the comment - I'm not sure that Mountain Standard Time is useful in Holland ;-P

Comment: @Rick-777 see the [documention](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#pkg-constants), the comment is the reference time used in format strings, it is defined as -0700 == MST and has nothing whatsoever to do with current timezone.

Answer (score 1):

Using the current time is just as easy

```golang
timestamp := time.Now().Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05")

fmt.Println(timestamp)
```